# Installing Windows error after formatting my HP computer's drive

Tags: windows-7, system-recovery

I have an HP ENVY Beats Special Edition 23-n012 Touchscreen All-in-One.

It was running very slow, with the disk usage always at 100%. I tried a full reset and also a Windows 10 installation, but it was still very slow.

I tried to install Windows 7. I got an error "not possible to install, as the Drive format is ***".

I deleted the drive and formatted it, but I still face the same issue.

Unfortunately, now I can't even repair the PC and install any OS. Any ideas how to fix this issue?

I am thinking about a Linux live CD and changing the partition to TFAS so I can install Windows 7.

Comment: More than likely you have a hardware problem, post the results. Go to this page and scroll down to "run tests when Windows does not start"....https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-beats-special-edition-23-n000-all-in-one-desktop-pc-series/6879113/model/7141595/document/c03467259

Comment: It's possible the drive is faulty/failing, however I'd try using the disk manger on a live Linux session to clean the disk, removing any existing partitions and leaving it ready for use but not partitioned or formatted in any way. I've sometimes found that existing partition tables can cause issues with the Windows installer when it encounters something it doesn't understand, and cleaning the disk first can avoid this and allow for successful imaging.

Comment: @music2myear yes. I exactly did that and installed a fresh copy of windows 7. Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible your drive is corrupted, faulty, or failing in some way.

But I'd try one more thing first.

Rather than trying to format the drive, just clean it.

In my experience, the Windows installer often has better success starting with an empty drive rather than a drive with partitions and formats already applied.

So, using either a Linux live disk or a WinPE disk, boot to the system and simply remove all existing partitions from the drive, and then try installing Windows.